# from moduleName import *

Tags: python, subprocess

In a main *.py, the statement

```
from myModule import a,b,c
```

imports the module 'myModule', and creates references in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can now use a and b and c in your program. But you need to use, for example:

```
print(myModule.a)
```

Now, I need to use the statement:

```
from myModule import *
```

and I need to access, in my main *.py file, at the values of some variables declared in 'myModule', for example:

```
print(a)
```

I tried to use globals() to declare global variables but then they are not imported in the current namespace.
Does anyone know hoe to solve this??
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to do this?  Using `import *` is considered bad practice. Use `import myModule` and then `myModule.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't clear but you can import modules with any moniker you want with:

```
import thing as t
```

And to access:

```
t.thingFunction.(foo)
```